# SSRS suppress blank line in export CSV

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have build a report in Report Builder which contains two tablix.
When exporting it in a CSV Format it is displaying a blank line between these 2 tables.

[image: Export CSV]

My aim is to remove the blank line from the csv while exporting the report.

I have already tried by adding a sub-report in the tablix even inserting the two tablix in rectangle or text box but no result.

Comment: Have you tried nesting both tables in a table?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3305/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-matrix-within-a-matrix/